# Implementando Grid Bootstrap 4 e SideNav

Tags: bootstrap, grid, bootstrap-4, sidebar

Olá, amigos.
Estou fazendo um projetinho e estou com dificuldades em usar grid e sidenav do bootstrap, quero fazer um menu fixo lateral, sem responsividade com 30% do tamanho da tela e os outros 70% vou implementar tabelas e forms, alguém poderia me ajudar?

O menu lateral consegui fazer uma parte, só não sei se está correto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

    <title>CRUD</title>
    <style>
        #sidebar-wrapper {
        left: -300px;
        width: 300px;
        background-color: #51A8B1;
        color: white;
        position: fixed;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        }
        .sidebar-nav {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 300px;
        list-style: none;
        }
        .sidebar-nav li {
        font-size: 20px;
        text-indent: 55px;
        line-height: 70px;
        }
        .sidebar-nav li a {
        color: white;
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        }
        .sidebar-nav li a:hover {
        background: #448B93;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        }
        .sidebar-nav li a:active, .sidebar-nav li a:focus {
        text-decoration: none;
        }

        #ufpb-logo{
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        padding-left: 110px;
        }
        #sidebar-wrapper.sidebar-toggle {
        transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
        margin-left: -200px;
        }

        #main{
        padding-left: 70px;

        }
        @media (min-width: 768px) {
        #sidebar-wrapper.sidebar-toggle {
            transition: 0s;
            left: 200px;
        }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!--SideNav-->
    <div class="container">
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="sidebar-toggle">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <div class="row" id="ufpb-logo">
                    <a href="#"><img width="111px" height="160" src="assets/img/ufpb2.png"/></a>
                </div>
                <li>
                    <a href="#item1">Produtos</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#item2">Entradas</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#item3">Saídas</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#item3">Resumo</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#item3">Sair</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código na verdade precisa de alguns ajustes. A começar pela primeira div com a classe Container. Na Verdade vc não vai precisar dela, por por default o Bootstrap coloca alguns valores nessa classe que não são interessantes pro seu Layout.

Outra coisa. Se vc quer parte da tela com 30% e a outra com 70% não faz sentido vc usar valores em PX.

Fiz esse modelo bem básico, tentando aproveitar o máximo do seu código e só retirando alguns valores em PX, Dessa forma dividi a tela com 30% na `#sidebar` e os outros 70% no `<main>` *(tem que fazer a parte da resposividade pra ficar tudo direitinho caso deseje)*

```css
#sidebar-wrapper {
background-color: #51A8B1;
color: white;
position: fixed;
height: 100%;
width: 30%;
z-index: 1;
}
.sidebar-nav {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
width: 30%;
}
.sidebar-nav li {
font-size: 20px;
text-indent: 55px;
line-height: 70px;
}
.sidebar-nav li a {
color: white;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
}
.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
background: #448B93;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}
.sidebar-nav li a:active, .sidebar-nav li a:focus {
text-decoration: none;
}

#ufpb-logo{
margin-top: 50px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
}
#sidebar-wrapper.sidebar-toggle {
transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

#main{
padding-left: 70px;

}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
#sidebar-wrapper.sidebar-toggle {
    transition: 0s;
}
}
main {
    background-color: tomato;
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="">
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="sidebar-toggle">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <div class="row justify-content-center" id="ufpb-logo">
                <a href="#"><img width="111px" height="160" src="assets/img/ufpb2.png"/></a>
            </div>
            <li>
                <a href="#item1">Produtos</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#item2">Entradas</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#item3">Saídas</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#item3">Resumo</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#item3">Sair</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <main>
        Seu conteudo
    </main>
</div>
```

**OBS1:** O código não está perfeito, vc ainda pode usar as classes do *Bootstrap4* Flex para melhor mais seu layout, segue o link da documentação oficial https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

**OBS2:** Com o Grid do Bootstrap vc não consegue fazer uma parte com 30% e outra com 70%, pois ele só trabalha com múltiplos de 12. O mais próximo que vc consegue chegar é usar Col-4 e Col-8 tendo uma porção de 33% e outra de 64% aproximadamente. Ver link da documentação: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/